# IIS 6.1 Server 2003 Web Apps Don't Startup on Reboot Sometimes

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, asp-classic

Occasionally when I reboot one of the servers at a client site the Web Apps running in IIS do not automatically start backup when the server is done rebooting.  The IIS service starts up just fine, its set to Auto Start and there are no errors in the event log.  Just none of the Web Apps are running, I have to click each one and click start.  This only happens occasionally, as they usually start but its completely baffling.

Any thoughts?  Its a mix of Classic ASP and ASP.NET applications. There are a total of 4 application pools running between around 8 web applications.

Comment: Please check whether you have the same problem as the one discussed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246598/application-pools-not-starting-after-iisreset

Comment: Hi Anil, nope that is not related to my issue.  On iisreset all my apps are started and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen when apps rely on a resource that is not yet available to the server, such as a network share.

Some people combat this problem by writing a Windows Service who's job is to check for such conditions and start the application.

Comment: I've considered this, but it sure does seem like a bug with IIS...Pretty lame!

Comment: .NET 4 has auto-start that may help: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx